# Implications of 2 entities sharing an android signing key

Tags: android, security, key, code-signing

I'm thinking about buying an existing android app from another developer. He has signed other apps not included in the sale with the same signing key as those included in the sale. What if any are the implications of sharing or duplicating the key and us both having a copy so we can update our owned apps? My main concern is can he update my newly purchased app without my permission or access to my developer account or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article/video on how to do an acquisition at [Phandroid](http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/). It does briefly address the idea of the signing key, but more from the seller's perspective. Regardless, I don't think it will be the worst thing in the world as while he could make a new signed APK of "your" app, he should not be able to publish it to Google Play after it's been transferred to your Google Account. He *could* try to distribute it through other means, but I wouldn't sweat it too much, especially if you're getting the conditions of the sale in a good contract.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I have seen the Phandroid link, but they are a little unclear on keys piece. The big question I have is, assuming the transfer with google goes through, can the previous owner still push an update to the existing app on the store without access to the google play developer account on which the app now currently resides?

Comment: If the app is transferred, then your Google Account will be the only one to control the Play Store listing and the .apk available there. The key does not give any access to the Play Store listing. The key only verifies the authenticity of an .apk after the user has downloaded it. The other dev *could* still build and sign an .apk that could be distributed by other methods (e-mail, direct download, etc.), but they could not do anything with the Play Store listing.

Answer (score 0):

Besides releasing a 'rogue' version of the app, another thing to note is that if the app is using signature permissions or sharedUserId, they could make another app that could potentially access and change data in the original app (via content providers, remote services, etc.) Even if the app is using neither of those, you might decide to add something in the future.